# Word to express something above awesome

Tags: word-choice

Consider the scenario -
Where someone tell me I earn this much money per month. And the amount is really huge. So express my surprise

1. That's insane amount of money.
   Is it correct to use insane ?
2. That's insane
3. That's awesome

Awesome is something common.
Is there a better way to express...

Comment: _Awesome_ really means _inspiring feelings of awe_. It has only become 'something common' because it is a currently fashionable slang word for 'very good'.

Comment: Remember that **amount** is a countable word, so it would have to be "**an** insane amount of money".